# Не загружается определенный сайт WebView Android

Tags: android, webview

Сделал просто приложение с WebView, которое должно загружать один сайт. Но именно этот сайт не загружается. Просто бесконечная анимация логотипа загрузки. JS включил.

```java
private WebView web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("https://tensy.org/");
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(web.canGoBack()){
            web.goBack();
        }else super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: а `google.com` отображается?

Comment: да, отображается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решилось добавлением команды:

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```